# Get URL of external site accessing my file

Tags: php

I have a script on my server that many sites use: mysite.com/counter.php

Other sites are using this file with the command "file_get_contents"
How can I get the URL of the sites accessing my file?

I would like to echo this via my mysite.com/counter.php file whenever external sites are accessing it:

```
Thank you Other_Site_URL_Here for using our script
```

Comment: The accessing programe does not necessarily represent a "site". It's not an URL accessing your site, it's a script or a tool.

Comment: +1, you can only have the IP address

Comment: how can I get the IP address then?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with `file_get_contents`, consider using tokens database. People who want your script would register and get special token. Then, they'd use your script with tokenized URL, like: `mysite.com/myscript/fs9dfyb87sdf8s`. You will be able to collect stats by token.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can only get the IP address.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Is the IP address. Keep in mind that proxies hide IP addresses, you then have to look into headers like `X-Forwarded-For`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - you cannot rely 100% on this value as this is a custom Header and can be easily amended.

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` - to get the IP Address (if empty try $_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For'])